# Does the default price include tax on Android Play console when using a template price that included tax?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am updating the subscription prices of my application. I have set up a pricing template to include tax. Like below:

[image]

When I am setting the pricing on the actual subscription page, it says "Default price doesn't include tax" (see below).

[image]

Is tax going to be added to the template prices I have set If I push this change, or will the price be already inclusive of vat, consistent with what I indicated on the pricing template creation page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some countries, prices shown to buyers on search and detail pages must equal the amount paid at time of payment. This means that all taxes (including VAT) must be included in the price.

So, all in all thats the base price exclusive of tak for non supported countries

We currently support tax-inclusive pricing in the following countries:

> Australia, Austria, Bahrain, Belarus, Belgium, Brazil, Bulgaria,
> Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France,
> Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, India, Ireland, Italy, Israel,
> Japan, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malaysia, Malta,
> Mexico, Netherlands, New Zealand, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania,
> Russia, Saudi Arabia, Serbia, Singapore, Slovakia, Slovenia, South
> Africa, South Korea, Spain, Sweden, Switzerland, Taiwan, Turkey,
> United Arab Emirates, United Kingdom

Ref:https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/138000?hl=en